# Size of String object vs custom made...object

Tags: java, class, memory

I have a class which has an

```
public class Sequence{

    ArrayList<String> obj
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now in my Main class I can do either of the following :

```
public class Main{

    // option 1 
    ArrayList< Sequence > xyz ...

    // option 2
    ArrayList< ArrayList< String > > abc......

}
```

Which of the above 2 options would occupy less space ?

Another way to put the question is, would directly using an ArrayList of Strings cost more memory than having an `ArrayList< Seq >` where `Seq` contains an ArrayList of Strings.

EDIT ==================================

The reason for asking this question is because I am working with a lot of those Seq objects. I am getting a out of memory exception. I was thinking of some way to reduce the memory usage, and I thought of removing all objects and working with raw data types.

Even if the memory usage difference between the ArrayList< Seq > and ArrayList< ArrayList< String > > is little. If I am working with 500 of those, I guess it would make a difference. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: I normally find when I think I need to use an ArrayList of an ArrayList there is usually a better collection, I just need another coffee.

Answer (score 0):

They are close enough in memory usage that you shouldn't worry about it.  This isn't going to be a major source of performance or memory usage for you.  The Strings are going to be the memory usage if you have enough of them.

Answer (score 0):

The class will "take more memory" because both the class and instances of it need to be in memory but... it doesn't matter. Don't worry about it.